# OpenVPN access to LAN devices

Tags: 14.04, networking, vpn, openvpn

Im trying to set up an OpenVPN by connecting my router to a VPS server running OpenVPN. By following this tutorial

[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-9-start-and-enable-the-openvpn-service][1]

I got it connected but I want to be able to access my LAN devices if I connect my phone to the OpenVPN.  However when I connect my phone to the OpenVPN im not able to connect to any of my LAN devices.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a directive like this to the config file. Adjust for your LAN ip range and server IP.

`route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.2`

Then restart the server.

Comment: Do you I need to add static routes on my router as well?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: Do I run this command? or add that line to the conf file?
'route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.2'